# Perl client socket->recv() Vs <> when server socket is invoking send multiple times

Tags: perl, sockets, recv

I have a perl server side socket that returns fields one by one invoking send() on the client socket.

I have no issues in reading all the fields at the client side if the code is like below:

```
while ($response = <$sock>) {
print "$response";
last if $response eq "END_OF_REQUEST";
}
```

But if the client side code is like below, it's going into a loop and is not working:

```
while(1) {      
$sock->recv($response, 1);
print "$response\n";    
last if $response eq "END_OF_REQUEST" ;
}
```

I agree that i can club all the fields and invoke only one send at the server side. But i am interested in knowing what's wrong with the 2nd approach. Does changing the LENGTH arg of the recv in 2nd approach does the trick?

I kind of started getting hands-on directly without proper theoretical knowledge about sockets. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl Q: socket->recv() vs. <>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599585/perl-q-socket-recv-vs)

Comment: You can check the arguments array by dumping the `@_` using perl debugger like this: `perl-d myscrpit.pl`.
For dumping the argument array, use `use Data::Dumper;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length argument to `recv()` is the *maximum* length of the message you want to receive, and `recv()` will never write more than that many characters into the buffer.  (What happens to the rest of the message depends on the type of the socket; for streaming sockets it'll be available for the next `recv()` call, while for datagram sockets it's simply thrown away.)

Thus, your `$sock->recv($response, 1);` will only write at most one character into `$response`.  Obviously, a one-character string can never equal `"END_OF_REQUEST"`.

The simple solution is to pass a sufficiently large maximum length to `recv()`, so that your message will not be truncated.

---

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

my ($rd, $wr) = IO::Socket->socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC)
    or die "socketpair: $!";
defined $wr->send("Hello, world!") or die "send: $!";
my $buf;
do {
    defined $rd->recv($buf, 9) or die "recv: $!";
    print qq(received: "$buf"\n);
} while ($buf !~ /!/);
```

This will output:

```
received: "Hello, wo"
received: "rld!"
```